# Javascript variable scope in HTML doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to construct a URL in an iframe. The URL parameters are parsed using jQuery in the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (!results) { return ''; }
  return results[1] || '';
}

var lidval = $.urlParam('lid');
var cidval = $.urlParam('cid');
var cyidval = $.urlParam('cyid');

</script>


<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%"  src="http://somerandomhost.com/Portal/index.php?task=nothankyou&lid='+lidval+'&cid='+cidval+'&cyid='+cyidval"></iframe>
```

I don't have visibility into the third party system at somerandomhost.com and at present, the response returned by that system is that the record isn't known in the database. However, I know the record exists, and so I believe the issue is that the URL isn't being correctly constructed. How can I get the URL to display in the body of the page so I can see what's going on? I think my variable scope may be wrong for a start?

Comment: Javascript variables aren't expanded in HTML.

Comment: Paste the URL into a new browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML won't be able to access your javascript variables. you will need to use document.write to construct your iframe tag. or try jquery for ease.

You can do this in jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (!results) { return ''; }
  return results[1] || '';
}

var lidval = $.urlParam('lid');
var cidval = $.urlParam('cid');
var cyidval = $.urlParam('cyid');
//construct url
var iframe_url = 'http://somerandomhost.com/Portal/index.php?task=nothankyou&lid='+lidval+'&cid='+cidval+'&cyid='+cyidval;

jQuery(function($){
 $('#your_frame_id').attr('src', iframe_url);
});
</script>


<iframe frameborder="0" id="your_frame_id" scrolling="no" width="100%"  src=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use javascript variables in the HTML document. You can only use those variables in the scope of that script tag. Try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (!results) { return ''; }
  return results[1] || '';
}

var lidval = $.urlParam('lid');
var cidval = $.urlParam('cid');
var cyidval = $.urlParam('cyid');

$('#someFrame').attr('src', "http://somerandomhost.com/Portal/index.php?task=nothankyou&lid="+lidval+"&cid="+cidval+"&cyid="+cyidval);

</script>

<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" id="someFrame"></iframe>
```

You will have to apply an `id` to the frame to find it.

It's also worth noting that adding functions ad-hoc to the jQuery variable is bad form. Try making a plugin http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: +1 Thanks for this Matt, I'll look into the plugin aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the iframe and set the src from your script.

```
$( '#myIframe' )[0].src = "http://somerandomhost.com/Portal/index.php?task=nothankyou&lid="+lidval+"&cid="+cidval+"&cyid="+cyidval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically write/open your iframe with your JavaScript variables. That should solve your issue.

Make your code something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (!results) { return ''; }
  return results[1] || '';
}

var lidval = $.urlParam('lid');
var cidval = $.urlParam('cid');
var cyidval = $.urlParam('cyid');

$("iframe").attr(src, 'http://somerandomhost.com/Portal/index.php?task=nothankyou&lid='+lidval+'&cid='+cidval+'&cyid='+cyidval');

</script>


<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%"  src=""></iframe>
```

Something like this, maybe not exactly this.

Comment: Also, wouldn't be a bad idea to give your iframe an id and cache it using JavaScript and use that.